# Writing summation expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, expression, minimize

How do I write an expression in Matlab code involving summation of a variable and then how do I minimize the expression?
ex. I need to minimize the following function

E= \sum_{i,j}[C_{ij}(r_{ij}) + C2_{ij}(r_{ij})^2]

I need to minimize the above expression for any values of r_{ij}s where i and j vary.

I could use the fmincon() in MATLAB but I am unable to write my expression suitably to give it as input to the fmincon().

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
E = sum(sum( C.*r + C2.*r.^2 ));
```

where `C`, `C2` and `r` are matrices of the same shape.

Answer (score 1):

`fmincon` and other optimization functions do not require you to write everything as an expression, they can optimize for functions as well.

```
function E = criterion(r, C, C2)
  e  = C.*r + C2.*r.^2;
  E  = sum(e(:));
```

I'm not completely sure about the syntax required by `fmincon`, but I guess it's something like `E = f(theta)`, where `theta` is a parameter vector you want adjusted such that `E` is minimal. Since I don't find your problem clearly described, I will assume your parameters are `C` and `C2` (in the case that `r` are your parameters, the case is similar and simpler).

As `fmincon` uses a vector to store the coefficients, we need a function that takes such a vector and transforms it into the sizes required by the `criterion` function above.

```
function E = criterionRolledC(theta,r)
  assert(numel(theta)==2*numel(r), 'The size of theta has to be twice the size of r');
  [M N] = size(r);
  C  = theta(1:M*N);      
  C2 = theta(M*N+1:end);
  C  = reshape(C , M, N);
  C2 = reshape(C2, M, N);

  E = criterion(r,C,C2);
```

That way, you can make an anonymous function that easily conforms to the interface of the optimizer: `@(theta)(criterionRolledC(theta,rValues))` will do when the variable `rValues` in your current workspace contains your `r` values.

In case you want the exact opposite, i.e. your parameters are `r`, it is simpler:

```
function E = criterionRolledR(theta,C,C2)
  assert(numel(theta)==numel(C), 'The size of theta has to be the same size as C');
  assert(all(size(C)==size(C2)), 'C and C2 need to have the same size');
  [M N] = size(C);
  r = reshape(theta, M, N);

  E = criterion(r,C,C2);
```

And you can construct an anonymous function similarly to the other case.